# Minidonda3 против pyvenv

Tags: python

Пытаюсь создать виртуальное окружение с Python 3 командой `pyvenv venv`, но мешает `miniconda`:

```
bash: /home/sergei/miniconda3/bin/pyvenv: Нет такого файла или каталога
```

Как вернуть `Python`, который стоял по умолчанию ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте создать так:
Создаем виртуальное окружение под названием "myvenv"

```
python3 -m venv myvenv
```

Активируем виртуальное окружение

```
source myvenv/bin/activate
```